# How to pass js variable from ajax into inner ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have ajax that return all the `claim_id`. From the `claim_id`, I call another ajax to get all the fields for this `claim_id`. But I unable to pass the value of `claim_id` from the first ajax into the success function in the inner ajax. It will always return the last value of the `claim_id`. How can I get the `claim_id` respectively?

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    var c_id = document.getElementById("c_id").value;

    $.ajax({
           url: '../rest/CategoryService/compcategory/'+c_id,
           type: 'POST',
           data: {
              format: 'json'
           },
           error: function() {
              $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
           },
           success: function(data) {

               //get the claim id
                for (i in data){            

                    var claim_id = data[i].iD;
                    // alert(claim_id); 

                    //get all the fields for the claim id
                    $.ajax({
                           url: '../rest/CategoryService/fieldcategory/'+claim_id,
                           type: 'POST',
                           data: {
                              format: 'json'
                           },
                           error: function() {
                              $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
                           },
                           success: function(data2) {

                               var textfield = "";
                               //construct the header fields                       
                               textfield += "<th>Sub Category</th>";

                               for (z in data2){    

                                   var field = data2[z].field;

                                   textfield += "<th>"+field+"</th>";

                               }

                               textfield += "<th>Action</th>";
                               alert(claim_id); 
                               alert(textfield);        

                                $("#tabledata"+claim_id+" thead").append(
                                "<tr>"+textfield+"</tr>");

                           },

                        });
                }
           },

        });

} );
```

Comment: Your code is confusing.Inside first success function you are creating a   getClaimData function and calling the same function from the same success block. You could have seperately created this function and call it inside success function

Comment: @user2181397 ok thanks for the advice.. i'll make my code cleaner..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define it in your second `ajax` `params` then use as `this.param_name` inside your success function

```
var claim_id = data[i].iD;

$.ajax({
    url: '../rest/CategoryService/fieldcategory/'+claim_id,
    claim_id: claim_id,  // defining your custome params here
    /*your other params*/
    success: function(data2) {

        alert(this.claim_id); // will alert your var claim_id variable
    }
});
```

Or the **second option** option is define global variable in your js and use it in success

Comment: var claim_id  can not bound to the `this`

Comment: why downvoted this answer? this method fix my problem! thanks

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN  **No it can** , as you can see it worked also for MissA

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem in your codes is the for loop will not wait for the ajax call to finish. That's the reason you are getting last `claim_id` always. Try below codes:

```
$(document).ready( function () {

        var c_id = document.getElementById("c_id").value;

        $.ajax({
               url: '../rest/CategoryService/compcategory/'+c_id,
               type: 'POST',
               data: {
                  format: 'json'
               },
               error: function() {
                  $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
               },
               success: function(data) {

                    var getClaimData = function(pointer, dataLength) {
                        var claim_id = data[pointer].iD;

                        $.ajax({
                               url: '../rest/CategoryService/fieldcategory/'+claim_id,
                               type: 'POST',
                               data: {
                                  format: 'json'
                               },
                               error: function() {
                                  $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
                               },
                               success: function(data2) {

                                   var textfield = "";
                                   //construct the header fields                       
                                   textfield += "<th>Sub Category</th>";

                                   for (z in data2){    

                                       var field = data2[z].field;

                                       textfield += "<th>"+field+"</th>";

                                   }

                                   textfield += "<th>Action</th>";
                                   alert(claim_id); 
                                   alert(textfield);        

                                    $("#tabledata"+claim_id+" thead").append(
                                    "<tr>"+textfield+"</tr>");

                                    pointer++;
                                    if(pointer < dataLength) {
                                        getClaimData(pointer, dataLength);
                                    }

                               },

                            });
                    };

                    getClaimData(0, data.length);
               },

            });

    });
```